# Хранение чисел с плавающей точкой MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongodb-query

интересует вопрос, как я могу хранить в MongoDB числа с плавающей точкой в виде - **0.000000000**, при попытке добавить число **0.000000000**, в коллекции появляется только **0.0**, а если записать **0.000000001**, то все записывается, но при получении, отображается как [image: введите сюда описание изображения], 
а в Studio 3T [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Интересует только один вопрос, как хранить данные с плавающей точкой, что бы можно было записать их в виде 0.000000000, и в таком же виде их получить.**

Заранее благодарен.

Answer (score 1):

Это не вопрос хранения данных, а вопрос отображения. 0 хранится в базе правильно.

Понимаете, база внутри себя не записывает "0.123" - она хранит фарш из битов, который имеет числовое значение 0.123. Но отображать на фронте его можно как угодно, и как 0.1, и как 0.1230000000 - это задача фронта-бэка, правильно сконвертить double в строку

Comment: Не буду спорить, но мне кажется как раз таки нет. 
Если я не ошибаюсь. 
Мне нужно получать это число, и прибавлять/отнимать его, и как я его буду хранить как 1 например, если мне нужно выводить на фронте его как 0.00012311.
http://prntscr.com/p4veaf
На примере другого приложения, там данные возвращаются в нужном виде - http://prntscr.com/p4vgef